# Troubleshooting ReactJS Display Issue with MediaPipe-Django API Integration for Exercise Rep Calculation Web App

Tags: python, django, mediapipe

I'm currently developing a web application that utilizes MediaPipe for calculating exercise repetitions. The backend is implemented using Django, which communicates with the frontend written in ReactJS via an API. However, I've encountered an issue where ReactJS seems unable to process the frames being sent by Django through the API.

As a result, the exercise interface isn't displaying anything at all, making it impossible to view or interact with the exercise calculation functionality. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem to ensure that ReactJS properly handles the frames received from Django via the API, allowing the exercise interface to display as intended?

In attempting to resolve the issue of ReactJS not processing frames sent by Django through the API, I initially checked for any potential errors in the data transfer between the backend and frontend. I reviewed the API endpoints, the data format being sent, and ensured that the communication between Django and ReactJS was properly established.